# Intellij Scala math functions import

Tags: scala, math, intellij-idea, import, package

New to Intellij IDEA/Scala so I'm wondering is there shortcut to auto import Scala packages.

Example:

```
package test
object TestClass extends App{
  var i = pow(22,22)
  println("Hello World" + i );
 }
```

It wont compile until import statment is added

```
import scala.math._
```

Coming from Eclipse/Java I expected CRTL + Shift O (or auto import) would offered me math package, must I type import myself ?

Comment: No, you simply need to write `math.pow` for it to search for the `math` class.

Comment: CLT + ALT + S auto import

Comment: @aravind CTRL+ ALT + S is not working, i think Yuval is right it cant be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  It depends on what you're searching for.

If you write `math` IntelliJ doesn't know what that is.  If you write `Math.`, that's already in scope and it will offer a menu of methods on the `Math` object.

If you write `Date`, *alt-enter* should bring up a menu of import options.  Choose one and the import statement will be inserted into your code.

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily. 
In your settings in IntelliJ you can set up auto import [by following these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/auto-import.html#d1808700e223). Alternatively, when you try and use a package that you do not have imported, it will tell you that it does not recognize what you are doing and show a red error. You can then autofill from the error (typically hit alt+enter) and it should solve the issue.